# Is a library ,created in .net version 4.0, access with in the lower version from its version

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am going to create my own library containing all my generic functions.
.
I want to make sure that if I create a library in .net framework 4.0 so I am able to call it in a class created in 3.5 or lower version.
.
I want to know some cautions before to start work on my library i.e. what kind of concepts should be cleared before to create your own library in order to use it in efficient way.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not make a 3.5 or lower version?

Comment: Just target .NET 3.5 (can be set in the project properties) and you are fine. Otherwise, your DLL can only be used from .NET 4.

Comment: can't understand will you please elaborate.thanks

Comment: @UsmanRazaAttari :check my answer . if it is helpful use it

Answer (score 0):

Create a library in .Net 2.0 Framework so there will be no issue with higher versions,

you can set the version from  `project properties` (*right click the project and select properties in visual studio)*

Select `Application` tab from properties window and select `Target Framework` combobox

select `.Net Framework 2.0`